Migrating an old module from Magento 2.3.6 to Magento 2.4
I held off on upgrading Magento to 2.4 for several years, and now I have to do it because of changes to the UPS API; one module we have, uGiftCert, cannot be purchased or updated anymore, and I am a couple of versions behind the first one that supported Magento 2.4; since upgrading, I noticed that we cannot view orders in the admin area, and the culprit seems to be this module.
I would like to continue using it, but I don't know what sort of things to look for to make this module compatible with Magento 2.4; I'm currently planning to write my own module that depends on Unirgy_Giftcert and uses preferences to replace the problematic PHP files with ones that work with Magento 2.4.
As a crude workaround, we could just find a new gift-certificate module and somehow migrate the existing certificates to the way the new module does things.

For the moment, I've been using the system log as my guide; I already fixed one major issue in which the item-name template in adminhtml was expecting a certain parameter to be passed in that the associated PHP file, before Magento 2.4, did not pass in; the error looked like this:
main.CRITICAL: Error: Call to a member function splitSku() on null in <magento_base>/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/items/column/name.phtml:26

The call stack said that the template was used with app/code/Unirgy/Giftcert/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Item/Name.php, which is based on vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Items/Column/Name.php; in Magento 2.3, the constructor for the \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Name class did not pass in an instance of \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data, and so neither does \Unirgy\Giftcert\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Item\Name in my version of the module.
However, the 2.4 version of that template calls splitSku() on an instance of \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data, so when the old version of the module loads that template, and the constructor does not pass in such an instance, the result is an attempt to call the function on null.

This is how I basically patched this in my own custom module; this file would be saved as app/code/Custom/Giftcert/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Item/Name.php:
<?php
namespace Custom\Giftcert\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Item;

use \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\OptionFactory;
use \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockConfigurationInterface;
use \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Registry;
use \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data as CatalogHelper;
use \Unirgy\Giftcert\Helper\Data as GCHelper;

class Name extends \Unirgy\Giftcert\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Item\Name
{
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
        StockConfigurationInterface $stockConfiguration,
        Registry $registry,
        OptionFactory $optionFactory,
        GCHelper $helper,
        array $data = [],
        ?CatalogHelper $catalogHelper = null
    ) {
        $data['catalogHelper'] = $catalogHelper ?? ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(CatalogHelper::class);
        parent::__construct($context, $stockRegistry, $stockConfiguration, $registry, $optionFactory, $helper, $data);
    }
}

The rest is basically boilerplate; below is app/code/Custom/Giftcert/registration.php:
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Custom_Giftcert',
    __DIR__
);

Then this is app/code/Custom/Giftcert/etc/module.xml:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Custom_Giftcert" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Unirgy_Giftcert" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>

Finally, this is where the preference comes in, app/code/Custom/Giftcert/etc/adminhtml/di.xml:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Unirgy\Giftcert\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Item\Name" type="Custom\Giftcert\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Item\Name" />
</config>

